# How to give add product option directly in cart in magento

Tags: cart, magento-1

I came across a requirement in one of my project where we need to accomplish the same.

**Requirement**:- Even though the user has not added any products to the cart, they should be able to open cart and click on a custom “Add product” to manually enter the **product sku** or **product name** with a type ahead feature to select the required product.

**Note** : We don't want the candidate to create a totally new custom cart functionality, requirement is to customize out of the box shopping cart of Magento so as to retain the inbuilt features.

Any suggestions/thoughts over this.